# Solve the matrices equation AX=B (tridiagonal matrices)

Tags: inverse, matrix-equations, tridiagonal-matrices

Solve this equation AX=B
\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & \ddots & 1 \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
\cdot X =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 1 & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 1 & 2 & \ddots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 2 & 1 \\
    0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 2
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
I have never found inverse of a nxn tridiagonal matrix and multiplied them before ($X = A^{-1}\cdot B$)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

By [**Gauss-Jordan method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix) we can easy see that

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & \ddots & 1 \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 & \ddots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: i already know it, but then how to multiply 2 matrices

Comment: We need to solve $AX=B \implies X=A^{-1}B$. Once we know $A^{-1}$ we can just multiply $A^{-1}B$ with the ordinary rules for [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).